# Why is Method DateTimeParse.TryParse(String, DateTimeFormatInfo, DateTimeStyles, DateTime&) Uninstrumented?

Tags: c#, pex

I've been trying to get some of the PEX samples working, but anything with DateTime.TryParse/DateTime.Parse produces dissapointing results. Pex does not come up with any interesting parameters, and if I wrap this with a reachable implication, it simply says 1 Missed Goal.

I think this must be because of the message I'm recieving about DateTimeParse.TryParse being uninstrumented, but why is it uninstrumented in the first place? Why does the document "Parameterized Test Patterns for Microsoft Pex" use DateTime as an example, if it does nothing interesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstrumented means that Pex hasn't explored the code and doesn't know the paths for it, so can't ensure that it will explore all the paths in your code, because it doesn't know how to explore the paths in `DateTime.TryParse`, in order to generate the outputs that would then be inputs to your code paths.  I hope you can follow that.

Therefore, if you allow Pex to instrument the `DateTime` class, it should be able to work out the paths in your code and generate some useful explorations.  Take a look at [Parameterized Unit Testing with Microsoft Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/pextutorial.pdf) Exercise 4, which hopefully will explain it a bit better than the document you've referenced.  Pex will only instrument objects you tell it to, as this is a potentially expensive operation (and could end up with a deep graph).

In the result of the Pex Explorations, Pex should give you a message in the information bar about the types that need instrumentation.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find anything on this a year ago.. I had assumed pex would have the built in assemblies explored already, but I understand how that could be quite expensive.